# Displaying notifications on top-right of primary monitor

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I'm using Natty 11.04 64bit, classic mode. I don't like the default setup of having two Gnome panels - one on top, one on bottom (seems like a waste of screen estate)

I basically merge both panels into a single panel at the bottom, in this arrangement:
[main menu] | [running apps] [indicator applet]

With this setup, all notifications are being displayed in the top-right of my secondary monitor, usually causing me to turn my head to read them, or missing the notification altogether.

As a test, I created a new Gnome panel, and positioned it at the top of my screen, so I had mirrored the default setup. I then moved the indicator applet from the bottom panel into the top one. When I received notifications, they were being displayed under the indicator applet, in the position I would like to see them.

Is there any way to get this behaviour with a single gnome panel at the bottom? I really don't want the top bar.

I've posted two screenshots that should help demonstrate what I mean:

http://postimage.org/image/29mb9dzfo/

http://postimage.org/image/29mcwxbxg/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can achieve this with [Notify OSD Configurator](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/tweak-notifyosd-notifications-in-ubuntu.html). I think in your case the positioning (Dynamic/Fixed) will be the thing you need to change.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I found that blog post. The same behaviour happens with fixed or dynamic -- it seems that using fixed just bumps the notification down by 40px or so (and there are no other options for controller its position)